# SQLite MAX on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, max

I have a database which has a table recording when a vehicle was last fuelled up. It has a date column of type integer.

I need to be able to determine which was the last fuel up date. I am using:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(FUEL_USE_TABLE_NAME, LAST_FUEL_UP_DATE_CLAUSE,
            REGISTRATION_NO_COLUMN + "=? ", new String[]{registrationNumber}, 
            null, null, null);
```

where `LAST_FUEL_UP_DATE_CLAUSE` is `MAX(date_time)`, where `date_time` is the name of the column in question.

This works fine when there are entries in the table, but whilst writing a unit test I expected the cursor's row count to be zero when there were no entries in the table, but instead I get a single row with value zero. I.e. the maximum value in the `date_time` column is zero, when in fact there are no values.

I'm happy to code around this (use `0` to signify no records instead of `-1`), but would like to know if this is expected behaviour, or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is expected behavior.

See SQLite documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)

Specifically it says:

> max(X)
>
> The max() aggregate function returns the maximum value of all values
>   in the group. The maximum value is the value that would be returned
>   last in an ORDER BY on the same column. Aggregate max() returns NULL
>   if and only if there are no non-NULL values in the group.

Comment: ".. value that would be returned last in an ORDER BY on the same column". Presumably this only applies if there are some values in the table. In my case there are no values so an ORDER BY query would return an empty cursor, I believe, which is different to the zero MAX() is returning.

Comment: It's an aggregate function.. it **always** returns one record, even if the DB is empty.  Says so right in the docs:  `Aggregate max() returns NULL if and only if there are no non-NULL values in the group.`  It makes sense (sorta), the value of that empty column is "0".  :p